# How do I put the values of a model into a database table, from inside a controller?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, database

I'm trying to learn ASP.net MVC. I'm using the pre-populated asp.net project that has a fake website within it to start. I have a form, and on submit, I want to put the values into a table in my database. I would also like to add functionality that if the email already exists in the database, I redirect them to another page.

I've added my own view, model, and controller.

Here's my databases (Side question: should I just put the table I created into DefaultConnection instead of Users.mdf?)

[image]

My Model:

```
public class RegisterLoyaltyViewModel
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public string EmailAddress { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Phone { get; set; }
    public string SecurityQuestion { get; set; }
    public string SecurityAnswer { get; set; }
    public string optSweepstakes { get; set; }
    public string optEmails { get; set; }
}
```

My relevant controller code:

```
 // POST: /Account/RegisterLoyalty
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    public void RegisterLoyalty(RegisterLoyaltyViewModel model)
    {
        //Currently nothing here
    }
```

I think what I need to do is hit the database inside the controller. I need to check if email already exists in the table, and if it does, redirect to page x. If email does not exist, simply submit the `model` to the database, and redirect to page y.

Answer (score 0):

You need a data layer implementation to hit the database, there are various ways of doing it one of which is using Entity Framework, have a look at [here](http://www.asp.net/entity-framework) to get some ideas, or alternatively you can use [ADO.NET](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/361579/A-Beginners-Tutorial-for-Understanding-ADO-NET) to connect to the database.

Comment: Hi @03Usr, I  walked through this guide for the Entity Framework (https://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/getting-started/getting-started-with-ef-using-mvc/creating-an-entity-framework-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application) and I now have a database and context set up, but I am still unsure how to take the data from a model and put it into the database itself.

Answer (score 0):

Create a controller action to GET the RegisterLoyalty view.  That view contains a the RegisterLoyalty form. Have the form POST to the RegisterLoyalty action.  Then you can perform your logic and add the model to the db if necessary.

```
//
// GET: /Account/RegisterLoyalty
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RegisterLoyalty()
{
    return View();
}

//
// POST: /Account/RegisterLoyalty
[HttpPost]
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult RegisterLoyalty(RegisterLoyaltyViewModel model)
{
    var db = new AccountLoyaltyDbContext();

    var emailExists = db.Loyalties.Any(x => x.EmailAddress == model.EmailAddress);

    if (emailExists)
    {
        return RedirectToAction("X");
    }

    db.Loyalties.Add(model);
    db.SaveChanges();

    return RedirectToAction("Y");
}

//
// GET: /Account/X
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult X()
{
    return View();
}

//
// GET: /Account/Y
[AllowAnonymous]
public ActionResult Y()
{
    return View();
}
```

---

RegisterLoyalty.cshtml

```
@model UserLoyalty.Models.RegisterLoyaltyViewModel

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "RegisterLoyalty";
}

<h2>RegisterLoyalty</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>RegisterLoyaltyViewModel</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.FirstName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.FirstName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.FirstName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.LastName, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.LastName, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.LastName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.EmailAddress, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.EmailAddress, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.EmailAddress, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Password, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Password, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Phone, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Phone, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Phone, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityQuestion, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityQuestion, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityQuestion, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SecurityAnswer, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.SecurityAnswer, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SecurityAnswer, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.optSweepstakes, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.optSweepstakes, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.optSweepstakes, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.optEmails, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.optEmails, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.optEmails, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>
```